# How to remove elements inserted in the errorPlacement of jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, jquery-validate

I made a survey form with html, php and yii2. I have used the jquery validation plugin to check whether each question has an answer. Now the validation works and an error message pops up when a question is not answered.

I have also added a "br" tag to change line so that the error message will not be in the same row of the radio buttons. Now when I select an answer the error message disappears, but the "br" tag still exists. So how do I remove the "br" tag tag as well?

The following are my codes:

```php
<?php

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    ?>

    <label class="question"><?php echo $question->getTitle(); ?></label><br>

    <?php
    foreach ($choices as $choice) {
        ?>

        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $question->id . 'radio'; ?>"
                                           value="<?php echo $choice->id; ?>"><?php echo $choice->getTitle(); ?></label>

    <?php }

    $this->registerJs('
                    rule[ "' . $question->id . 'radio"] = {
                            required: true,
                            }

                ', View::POS_BEGIN);
    ?>

<?php } ?>

<?php
$this->registerJs('

                    $(document).ready(function(){

                    $("#testForm").validate({
                    rules: rule,
                    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                        if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox" || element.attr("type") == "radio") {
                            error.insertAfter($(element).parents("label").prev($(".question"))); 
                            $("<br>").insertAfter($(element).parents("label").prev($(".question"))); 
                        }

                        else{
                            error.insertAfter(element);
                        }

                    }

                    });
                });

                ',
    View::POS_END);
?>
```

Comment: You should make your life easier by using Yii provided classes for forms rather than building you own html and like above use `ActiveForm` to build your inputs and you dont have to add a `<br>` manually

Comment: I agree with Muhammad, if that happens that you can not use `ActiveForm` try to bind your selector on `change` event and get the `parent` class `form-group` and `find('br')`. in this case only jquery helps you. Good luck

Comment: Yeah... don't do it like that... there are better ways to achieve same layout.  You could change the error message container from a `label` to something else and apply any CSS rules you wish.  `label` is "inline" element.  `div` is "block" element.  I think you could easily eliminate the need for insertion of a `br`.